# Removing key value pair from yaml dictionary in python

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

We would like to remove the key and the values from a YAML file using python, for example

```
- misc_props:
  - attribute: tmp-1
    value: 1
  - attribute: tmp-2
    value: 604800
  - attribute: tmp-3
    value: 100
  - attribute: tmp-4
    value: 1209600
  name: temp_key1
  attr-1: 20
  attr-2: 1
- misc_props:
  - attribute: tmp-1
    value: 1
  - attribute: tmp-2
    value: 604800
  - attribute: tmp-3
    value: 100
  - attribute: tmp-4
    value: 1209600
  name: temp_key2
  atrr-1: 20
  attr-2: 1
```

From the above example we would like to delete the whole bunch of property and where key name matches the value, for example if we want to delete name: temp_key2 the newly created dictionary after delete will be like below:-

```
- misc_props:
  - attribute: tmp-1
    value: 1
  - attribute: tmp-2
    value: 604800
  - attribute: tmp-3
    value: 100
  - attribute: tmp-4
    value: 1209600
  name: temp_key1
  attr-1: 20
  attr-2: 1
```

Comment: Please include the code that you have when posting on SO, even if it is not working completely as expected (or not at all), you can get valuable feedback on why your code is not working and/or what your invalid assumptions are.

Answer (score 1):

It is not sufficient to delete a key-value pair to get your desired output.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
with open('input.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
del data[1]['misc_props']
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

as that gives:

```
- misc_props:
  - attribute: tmp-1
    value: 1
  - attribute: tmp-2
    value: 604800
  - attribute: tmp-3
    value: 100
  - attribute: tmp-4
    value: 1209600
  name: temp_key1
  attr-1: 20
  attr-2: 1
- name: temp_key2
  atrr-1: 20
  attr-2: 1
```

What you need to do is delete one of the items of the sequence that is
the root of the YAML structure:

```
del data[1]
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- misc_props:
  - attribute: tmp-1
    value: 1
  - attribute: tmp-2
    value: 604800
  - attribute: tmp-3
    value: 100
  - attribute: tmp-4
    value: 1209600
  name: temp_key1
  attr-1: 20
  attr-2: 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try using the yaml module?

```
import yaml
with open('./old.yaml') as file:
    old_yaml = yaml.full_load(file)

#This is the part of the code which filters out the undesired keys
new_yaml = filter(lambda x: x['name']!='temp_key2', old_yaml) 

with open('./new.yaml', 'w') as file:
    documents = yaml.dump(new_yaml, file)
```

Comment: The yaml module only partially supports loading of YAML 1.1. YAML 1.2 has been available for over ten years. Your code also removes all comments in a YAML file, and causes any unicode in the file to be written as escape coes. When you recommend PyYAML to someone is already using ruamel.yaml, you should make clear all the problems and disadvantages of doing that downgrade. Did you actually run your code? If you would have you'ld see you get output starting with `!!python/object/apply:builtins.filter`, not what the OP expects.